# Porque está dando laço infinito?

Tags: c

> Exercicio:  Escrever um algoritmo para gerar e escrever uma tabela com
>   s valores do seno de um ângulo A em radianos, utilizando a série de
>   Mac-Laurin truncada, apresentada a seguir:
>
> A3
>   A5
>   A7
>   sen A = A - 6 + 120 - 5040
>
> Condições: os valores dos ângulos A devem variar de 0.0 a 6.3, inclusive, de 0.1 em 0.1.

meu código :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main () {

    float A = 0.0, valor_seno;
    float aprs_tela;

    while (A <= 6.3) {
        aprs_tela = A;
        A = A - (((pow(A,3) / 6) + (pow(A,5) / 120)) - (pow(A,7) / 5040));
        valor_seno = sin(A);

        printf("O valor do seno (%.1f) com a série de Mac-Laurin é %.2f\n\n",aprs_tela ,valor_seno);

        A = A + 0.1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No início do programa tu coloca que `A = 0.0`; (A vai receber 0).
Depois você verifica se `A` é `<` que `6,3` (SIM, para o primeiro laço isso é verdadeiro).

Depois você executa a linha:

```
A = A - (((pow(A,3) / 6) + (pow(A,5) / 120)) - (pow(A,7) / 5040));
```

Acontece que A é igual a zero, e zero elevado a qualquer número é zero. Em resumo, `(((pow(A,3) / 6) + (pow(A,5) / 120)) - (pow(A,7) / 5040))` isso tudo vai dá zero.
Aí você tenta atribuir `A = A - [expressao];` (Ou seja A (que é zero) vai receber o resultado da expressão, que também é zero.

Aí depois você coloca:

```
A = A + 0.1;
```

blz aqui tu atribui um valor positivo a "A".
Só que um valor diminuído de um valor maior, esse será sempre menor, por exemplo: `0 - 0,1 = -0,1` (Ou seja o valor de A sempre será menor que 6,3 por isso fica em laço infinito).

Dá pra entender?

Comment: Veja [aqui](/editing-help) como formatar as postagens. Há também os atalhos de teclado, e a barra de formatação na versão "não mobile" do site, com boa parte dos comandos possíveis.